# display and justify content not clear anyone can help me

Tags: html, css

Html css display and justify content not clear any one can help me

I am trying to learn display properties

i have tried to learn but not clear till now

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) and see the examples

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For `display` check out: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp .
For `justify-content` check out : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

Answer (score -1):

hello you can search in google Mdn this site can help you in display:flex; you can type in search box site display all of tham display visible for you but I will explain first look display for styling the container or body or card but before use the display you set the width to the body or container ok you can Be familiar very to display search in mdn and read the document ok have nice time goodbye